# Can Toroidal High Voltage Capacitors Cause Time Dilation?

Tags: time, capacitance

I read in NASA's Warp Mechanics, they managed to warp space time with a high voltage toroidal capacitor, as detected by an interferometer. So I was wondering, is it possible to dilate time with this method? Thank you

Comment: NASA warp mechanics 101 and 102

Comment: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110015936/downloads/20110015936.pdf